# Read a decimal number from a file and then convert it to hexadecimal using C Shell

Tags: csh, bc

I have the following code to convert a decimal number to hexadecimal number. I don't know if the syntax is correct, but `$output2` is basically a list of numbers like :

```
318
415
362

set conv=`echo 'ibase=10; obase=A <$output2>'| bc`
echo "$conv"
```

And I need to see something like this:

```
13E
19F
16A
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
mathb@Balu:~$ echo "obase=16; $output2" | bc
13E
19F
16A
```

EDIT: Just noted that the question was on Csh. Here's the updated answer:

```
% echo $_
/bin/csh
% echo $output2
318 415 362
% printf '%x\n' $output2
13e
19f
16a
%
```

Comment: I wrote in that way: 
set conv=`echo "obase=16; $output2"| bc`
echo "$conv" and I got (standard_in) 1: syntax error
I also added: set conv=`echo "ibase=10; obase=16; $output2"| bc` and the result is the same.

Comment: @LilianaGonzálezArciniega See my edited answer. My initial answer was on `bash`.